# Regex in R question: Unable to break out prices

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to break off prices from the end of each string. For example,

```
"flsdlsdlkndl 56.00"
"jdnsl3492nlks sdjnflld dklsdn3 dklncs3 4.55"
"jcks39... o93003nlkds...ksdclsnc 7.88"
"jlsnl/() dnklsdlk2 ksldclk2 -eln 6.77"
```

Basically at the end of each string is a price with a number in dollars and cents. I'm having a difficult time coming up with the perl expression to just pull digits with a decimal point at the end of a string.

I could use `gsub(perl_ex, data, perl=T)`, but cannot get the right expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `gsub` by using `".* "` inside it.

```
a <- "jlsnl/() dnklsdlk2 ksldclk2 -eln 6.77"
b <- "flsdlsdlkndl 56.00"
c <- "jdnsl3492nlks sdjnflld dklsdn3 dklncs3 4.55"
d <- "jcks39... o93003nlkds...ksdclsnc 7.88"
```

For example `gsub(".* ","",b)` gives `56.00` or `gsub(".* ","",a)` gives `6.77`.

Of course you can put all data at once as well,

```
alldata <- c("flsdlsdlkndl 56.00",
"jdnsl3492nlks sdjnflld dklsdn3 dklncs3 4.55",
"jcks39... o93003nlkds...ksdclsnc 7.88",
"jlsnl/() dnklsdlk2 ksldclk2 -eln 6.77")

gsub(".* ","",alldata)

"56.00" "4.55"  "7.88"  "6.77"
```

Comment: Note that this will work for the current examples, but it does not take the format of the price into account as it matches until the last occurrence of a space.

Comment: I know the point thank you. I worked on the example data and the necessity in here was splitting out the very last thing after the last space.

Comment: Awesome solution and very versatile!

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)?$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/pytLVr/1/).

---

In base `R` (remember to set `perl = TRUE` and add backslashes):

```
strings <- c("flsdlsdlkndl 56.00",
             "jdnsl3492nlks sdjnflld dklsdn3 dklncs3 4.55",
             "jcks39... o93003nlkds...ksdclsnc 7.88",
             "jlsnl/() dnklsdlk2 ksldclk2 -eln 6.77")

sub(".*?(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)$", "\\1", strings, perl = T)
[1] "56.00" "4.55"  "7.88"  "6.77"
```

Comment: `sub(".*?(\\d+\\.\\d+)$", "\\1", strings)` should be ok?

Comment: @RonakShah: You're totally right, `sub` will perfectly do.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `stri_extract_last_regex` which extracts the last specified regex

```
as.numeric(stringi::stri_extract_last_regex(x, "\\d+\\.\\d+"))
#[1] 56.00  4.55  7.88  6.77
```

**data**

```
x <- c("flsdlsdlkndl 56.00", "jdnsl3492nlks sdjnflld dklsdn3 dklncs3 4.55", 
  "jcks39... o93003nlkds...ksdclsnc 7.88","jlsnl/() dnklsdlk2 ksldclk2 -eln 6.77")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `sub` from `base R`

```
as.numeric(sub(".*[^0-9.]([0-9.]+)$", "\\1", x))
#[1] 56.00  4.55  7.88  6.77
```

---

Or with `regmatches/regexpr` from `base R`

```
as.numeric(regmatches(x, regexpr("[0-9.]+$", x)))
#[1] 56.00  4.55  7.88  6.77
```

#### data

```
x <- c("flsdlsdlkndl 56.00", "jdnsl3492nlks sdjnflld dklsdn3 dklncs3 4.55", 
   "jcks39... o93003nlkds...ksdclsnc 7.88","jlsnl/() dnklsdlk2 ksldclk2 -eln 6.77")
```